# DASK Delayed and modules with multiple return variables

Tags: python, dask, dask-delayed

I want to use delayed function from DASK. Unfortunately, Using delayed function on modules with multiple return values is not clear to me. For example, if I run following snippet, there is no way to point out to the first return value of  ***inc*** module after computing final result.

```
from dask import delayed
from time import sleep

def inc(x):
    sleep(1)
    return x+1, x+2

def add(x, y):
    sleep(1)
    return x + y

x = delayed(inc)(1)
y = delayed(inc)(2)
z = delayed(add)(x[0], y[0])
print(z.compute())
```

Correctly, the result of this snippet is as follow. This indicates pointing is working.

```
(3, 5)
```

However, I can not read x return's value.

```
%%time
result=z.compute()
print('Result is :', result)
print(x[0])

output: 
Result is : 5
Delayed('getitem-f80cf501fe43d6cbd50e0bec71c91c12')
CPU times: user 7.46 ms, sys: 2.13 ms, total: 9.59 ms
Wall time: 2 s
```

It would be nice to read delayed function's return value without computing them if they are already computed because of dependency.

Answer (score 0):

By default Dask's `compute` method returns concrete results, but cleans up all intermediate results.  This is especially important for workloads that require a lot of memory.  It is important to clean up intermediate results on the fly.

If you want to compute many results at the same time, consider the dask.compute function.

```
x, z = dask.compute(x, z)
```